# Use a picture as the initial distribution of an agent based model

Tags: differential-equations, image-processing, image, modeling

I am trying to make an [agent based model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Agent-based_model) similar to

- http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/DiffusionLimitedAggregationARealTimeAgentBasedSimulation/
- http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/PredatorPreyEcosystemARealTimeAgentBasedSimulation/

to approximate the solution to a system of PDEs which describe two interacting populations (i.e. Prey and predators).

I would like to specify the initial distribution with a simple picture such as one of these two:

```
img = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/9io21.gif"]
```

[image]

```
img = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/J2JQK.png"]
```

[image]

where white and black represent the distribution of two different populations.

Also is it possible to turn a picture into a distribution function in two dimensions?

Comment: What do you mean by "a distribution function in two dimensions"?

Comment: @C.E. This is a complex request and may be very difficult to do for an arbitrary image. What I am asking for is some code that takes a image that produces either level curves, piece wise function, or some other function. i.e. a square can be described by the piecewise function u(x,y)=1 if (x,y) ∈[0,1], 0 if (x,y)∉[0,1]

Comment: ok, I understand what you mean now. I added something about that to my answer.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You have to use `ColorNegate` and other image processing functions to make the area that you want to sample is white, while the rest is black. After that you can use `ImageMesh` and `RandomPoint` like this:

```
img = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/J2JQK.png"];

mesh = ImageMesh[ColorNegate[img]];
pts = RandomPoint[mesh, 500];

Show[mesh,ListPlot[pts, PlotStyle -> Red]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
img = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/9io21.gif"];

mesh = ImageMesh[ColorNegate[img]];
pts = RandomPoint[mesh, 500];

Show[mesh, ListPlot[pts, PlotStyle -> Red]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

To check if a point is inside the region, you might use `RegionMember`. This could be used as a "distribution function". (In this example, `mesh` corresponds to the first image in this answer.)

```
f = RegionMember[mesh];
{f[{0, 0}], f[{1500, 1500}]}
```

> `{False, True}`

Comment: This is helpful. How can I do the same with the white space? I have replaced by original picture with a transparent (not white background) to make this easier. (Link to new pic:https://i.stack.imgur.com/J2JQK.png so have to download it to see that it is transparent)

Comment: @AzJ With the new transparent version all you have to do is remove `ColorNegate` to get the opposite part.

Answer (score 7):

you can use `PixelValuePositions`

```
Show[image, MapThread[Graphics[{#2, Point@RandomSample[PixelValuePositions[image, #1], 
   2000]}] &, {{0, 1}, {Red, Blue}}]]
```

[image]

of course there are some outlying points and that is because your image has a thin white border surrounding it

Comment: @C.E. you are right. No need to replace. I was not clearly thinking. Thanks for letting me know !

Comment: @C.E. i edited the answer